# Задача на разбор случаев

Tags: python

**Готов ответить на любые вопросы по моему коду**

Условие такое: Напишите программу, которая по изображению поля для игры в «Крестики-нолики» определит, могла ли такая ситуация возникнуть в результате игры с соблюдением всех правил.

Напомним, что игра в «Крестики-нолики» ведется на поле 3*3. Два игрока ходят по очереди. Первый ставит крестик, а второй – нолик. Ставить крестик и нолик разрешается в любую еще не занятую клетку поля. Когда один из игроков поставит три своих знака в одной горизонтали, вертикали или диагонали, или когда все клетки поля окажутся заняты, игра заканчивается.
Я написал следующий код, но я получаю WA на 21 тесте:

```
a = []
a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
k = 0
one = 0
two = 0
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j == 1:
            one += 1
        elif j == 2:
            two += 1
b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = b6 = b7 = b8 = 0
for_two = 0
if a[0][0] == a[0][1] == a[0][2] != 0:  # 1 строка
    k += 1
    b1 = 1
    if a[0][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[1][0] == a[1][1] == a[1][2] != 0:  # 2 строка
    k += 1
    b7 = 1
    if a[1][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[2][0] == a[2][1] == a[2][2] != 0:  # 3 строка
    k += 1
    b8 = 1
    if a[2][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[0][0] == a[1][0] == a[2][0] != 0:  # 1 столбец
    k += 1
    b2 = 1
    if a[2][0] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[0][1] == a[1][1] == a[2][1] != 0:  # 2 столбец
    k += 1
    b4 = 1
    if a[2][1] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[0][2] == a[1][2] == a[2][2] != 0:  # 3 столбец
    k += 1
    b5 = 1
    if a[2][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[0][0] == a[1][1] == a[2][2] != 0:  # главная диагональ
    k += 1
    b3 = 1
    if a[2][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if a[2][0] == a[1][1] == a[0][2] != 0:  # побочная диагональ
    k += 1
    b6 = 1
    if a[0][2] == 2:
        for_two = 1
if one - two < 0 or one - two > 1:
    print("NO")
elif k > 2:
    print("NO")
elif k == 1:
    if for_two == 1 and one - two == 0:
        print("YES")
    elif one - two == 0:
        print("NO")
    else:
        print("YES")
elif k == 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    if b1 == 1 and (b1 == b2 or b1 == b4 or b1 == b5 or b1 == b3 or b1 == b6):
        print("YES")
    elif b2 == 1 and (b2 == b7 or b2 == b8 or b2 == b3 or b2 == b6):
        print("YES")
    elif b5 == 1 and (b5 == b7 or b5 == b8 or b5 == b3 or b5 == b6):
        print("YES")
    elif b8 == 1:
        if b8 == b2 or b8 == b4 or b8 == b5 or b8 == b3 or b8 == b6:
            print("YES")
        else:
            print("NO")
    elif b7 == 1 and (b7 == b4 or b7 == b3 or b7 == b6):
        print("YES")
    elif b4 == 1 and (b4 == b3 or b4 == b6):
        print("YES")
    elif b3 == 1 and b3 == b6:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Пример теста:

```
2 1 1
1 1 2
2 2 1
```

Ответ

```
YES
```

Comment: Могла возникнуть любая ситуация, если нет победы, если количество крестиков отличается от количества ноликов не более чем на 1. Анализ поля здесь не обязателен, крестики нолики довольно простая игра.

Comment: @ganz именно в этом и вопрос)). Я не понимаю что я упустил? Может быть контр - тесты скинете , если можете

Comment: вижу проблемму тут if one - two < 0 or one - two > 1: если равно минус один, то ходили первыми нолики мб abd(one-two)>1. Так же остальные проверки не понимаю, что ты хотел сделать, ведь при первых проверках должно возникнуть состояние "невозможно".... хотя ведь состояние победы это валидное состояние, значит нужно проверить лишь количиство крестиков и ноликов.

Comment: @ganz  первым всегда начинает крестик = 1

Comment: тут if one - two < 0 or one - two > 1  я проверяю на "невозможно"

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, будет ли полезно решение реализованное на C++, но на всякий вот оно.
P.S. Код прошел все тесты

```
using namespace std; 

int main() {
int matrix[3][3];
int counter=0, counter_for_1 = 0, counter_for_2 = 0, line=0, main_diagonal=0, secondary_diagonal=0, column=0;
bool wintwo=false, winone = false;

ifstream in ("input.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (line == 3) {
        counter++;
        winone = true;
    }
    if (line == 6) {
        counter++;
        wintwo = true;
    }
    line = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        //Считываем из файла данные
        in >> matrix[i][j];
        //Считаем количество еденичек
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            counter_for_1++;
        }
        //Считаем количество двоек
        if (matrix[i][j] == 2) {
            counter_for_2++;
        }
        //Пробегаемся по строкам и ищем количество выйгрышных
        line += matrix[i][j];
        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            line += 10;
        }
        //Определяем выйгрышная ли главная диагональ
        if (i == j) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                main_diagonal += 10;
            }
            main_diagonal += matrix[i][j];
        }
        //определяем выйгрышная ли побочная диагональ
        if (i + j == 2) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                secondary_diagonal += 10;
            }
            secondary_diagonal += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }           
}

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (column == 3) {
        counter++;
        winone = true;
    }
    if (column == 6) {
        counter++;
        wintwo = true;
    }
    column = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        //Определяем выйгрышная ли колонка
        column += matrix[i][j];
        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            column += 10;
        }
    }
}

if (main_diagonal == 3) {
    counter++;
    winone = true;
}
if (main_diagonal == 6) {
    counter++;
    wintwo = true;
}
if (secondary_diagonal == 3) {
    counter++;
    winone = true;
}
if (secondary_diagonal == 6) {
    counter++;
    wintwo = true;
}

//Финальная проверка на повторные ходы участников и выставление коэффициентов
if (wintwo == false && winone == false) {
    if ((counter_for_1 - counter_for_2) > 1){
        counter += 10;
    }
    if ((counter_for_1 - counter_for_2) < 0) {
        counter += 10;
    }
}

if (wintwo == true && winone == true) {
    counter += 10;
}

if (winone == true) {
    if (counter_for_1 == counter_for_2) {
        counter += 10;
    }
    if ((counter_for_1 - counter_for_2) > 1) {
        counter += 10;
    }
    if ((counter_for_1 - counter_for_2) < 0) {
        counter += 10;
    }
    if ((counter_for_1 + counter_for_2) == 9) {
        counter --;
    }
}

if(wintwo == true) {
    if (counter_for_1 != counter_for_2) {
        counter += 10;
    }
}

//Вывод полученных результатов
if (counter < 2) {
    cout << "YES";
}
else {
    cout << "NO";
}
```

}